# Which modifier do I use to twist this object horizontally in this way (video)?

Tags: modifiers

I want to slightly twist (or bend, displace, screw or curve?) an object in blender.
It’s an imported SVG object with an applied solidify modifier (and with lots of weird vertices).

Here’s my file: [image]

And here is a video of what I want to to animate (the actual object): https://youtu.be/H0QXHbf7TVo
I want it to displace horizontally.

I tried to use a simple deform and a curve but I don’t get the desired result.

How do I make the object twist this way?

[image: The blender object]

Comment: Looks like half of a loop of a screw.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can achieve this with a *Simple Deform* modifier as your two tips are actually moving forward and backward, maybe you should try a *Lattice* modifier (or *Surface Deform* modifier), give it 2 shape keys and switch from shape key 1 to shape key 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The Lattice worked out great! :)